# Round brackets, curly braces

Tags: f#

I am trying to understand this code:
https://github.com/CameronAavik/AdventOfCode/blob/master/Challenges/2018/Day03.fs

But I couldn't find any info about this "let something (...) { ... } = ..."syntax, for example:

```
let processBoundary (prevY, claimSet, total) {cursor=cursor; isAdding=isAdding; data=(top, height)} = ...
```

what is this? reminds me to a tuple and destructuring, but maybe it is not that.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually destructuring as with a tuple, just that it's a record in this case.

A notable difference is that while with a tuple you have to match the exact number and position of the individual parts, when destructuring a record, you can leave out any of the fields you're not interested in at that point.

I wrote a (non-exhaustive) [blog post](http://teadrivendev.github.io/2016/01/04/pattern_matching_record_fields/) on different ways of pattern matching/destructuring in F# once; maybe that's helpful in understanding here.

Comment: hi,
So for example processBoundary takes a tuple which has 3 fields, and a record, and from the record it destructs 2 fields.

Comment: Yes. It actually does even more in this example, because one of the three fields it matches out of the record, one is a tuple which itself is deconstructed again. (In all I have to say that I don't find that example a great piece of F# code to learn from, because readability and understandability don't seem to have been much of a focus for the author.)